# how to add valaue of checkbox to url when checkbox clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

```
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="<?php echo $catrecord[0] ; ?>"/>
```

This is the check box and when some one select it i want to go to another url with checkbox valaue in url, not as post.

this is the place i wanna append checkbox valaue
case 'Addnew':

```
window.location = '<?php echo JURI::base()."index.php?option=com_flatorb&view=entity"?>';
break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below,

**Method 1**

```
$('.messageCheckbox').change(function(){
   if(this.checked)
      window.location = 'index.php?option=com_flatorb&view=entity&value=' + $(this).val('');
});
```

**Method 2**

```
$('.messageCheckbox').change(function(){
   if($('#edit-checkbox-id').is(':checked'))
      window.location = 'index.php?option=com_flatorb&view=entity&value=' + $(this).val('');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind change event handler with checkbox and use window.location to open page.

```
$('#checkboxId').change(function(){
   if(this.checked)
      window.location = 'index.php?option=com_flatorb&view=entity&chkValue=' + this.value;
});
```

Comment: You are welcome, I just checked you do not have id in checkbox, I think you need value of check and I updated my answer for value.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.[name of form].[name of checkbox].checked
```

or with jQuery:

```
$('#[id of checkbox]').is(':checked');
```